# Is "ruby script/plugin" a command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was following an online tutorial to create an Ruby on Rails application on App Engine.

There is one command which other people can run, but it didn't run on my Ubuntu 10.10:

```
ruby script/plugin install http://svn.avdi.org/nulldb/trunk/
```

When I try to run it, it complains: `ruby1.8: No such file or directory script/plugin (LoadError)`

What is wrong with my computer?

```
ruby  -v  ==> 1.8.7
rails -v  ==> 2.3.10  
gem   -v  ==> 1.3.7
```

Comment: Is there a script directory within your rails application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just plain old `script/plugin install http://svn.avdi.org/nulldb/trunk/` ? Also are you sure that you're in the correct directory?(the rails project main directory) And are you sure that you have the file script/plugin?

Comment: yes.. i think u r right.. 
i check it.. i am in the root.. but do not have the plugin  folder...

Comment: The plugin folder is under vendor, the *script* you run is just the file script/plugin

Answer (score 21):

if using rails3, cd into your rails app root dir then use

```
rails plugin install http://url/of/your/package
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Rails 3, you no longer have a `script/plugin` directory.

Rails 3 now runs commands through the "rails" script.

You can find your version of rails with `rails -v`

Comment: hi, i am using rails 2.3.10,  since that project not release support for rails 3

Comment: As mentioned below, the full command in rails 3 is `rails plugin install path.to.your.plugin` where 'path.to.your.plugin' is something like 'git://github.com/hiroshi/script-refactor.git'

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem with rfacebook on rails 3
solution that worked for me:

```
cd \MyAppName\app

rails plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/rfacebook/trunk/rfacebook/plugins/rfacebook
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that you are running that command from the root of your rails app.